# Laravel : My app doesn't get routed

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running my first laravel app for the first after hours struggling with dependencies installation errors.

Sorry it might be tiny mistake but seems I couldn't find out.

Picture are darker, computer is being broken.

[image]

***app/Http/routes.php***

```
<?php

// view('helloworld') ==> helloworld.blade.php
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('helloworld');
});
```

***resources/view/helloworld.blade.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
   <head>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class = "container">       
         <div class = "content">

         </div>
        <p> Yo test....test..</p>   
      </div>
   </body>

</html>
```

when I hit `http://localhost:8000/`, it gaves me (even after refreshing) :

[image]

Why doesn't `'/'` get routed ? It's laravel 5, the latest one.

Comment: The latest Laravel as in 5.3?  Then app/Http/routes.php isn't the correct location.

Comment: you should have your route code in `routes/web.php` in laravel 5.3

Comment: My god here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_routing.htm told me wrong folder (-_-")....

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup, not surprising.  Laravel 5.3 was released quite recently and in Laravel 5.0 through 5.2, that was the correct location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3, the Http routes file was switched to the routes/ directory.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing

> All Laravel routes are defined in your route files, which are located in the routes directory. These files are automatically loaded by the framework. The routes/web.php file defines routes that are for your web interface. These routes are assigned the web middleware group, which provides features like session state and CSRF protection. The routes in routes/api.php are stateless and are assigned the api middleware group.

Answer (score 1):

can you check in incognito or maybe you should remove the welcome.blade.php file

Answer (score 1):

you should have your web page routes in `routes/web.php` in laravel 5.3 !